# Is there a proven way to manage a collection of atoms in Recoil?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state-management, recoiljs

I'm testing Recoil and I need to manage a list of posts to display in the homepage.

My first idea was to make a big Atom with all the posts, but this seems a bit violent as we can edit posts directly on the homepage.

My second idea was to dynamically generate atoms with a prefix:

```js
const onePost = (postId: string) => atom({
  key: 'post_' + postId,
  default: null,
  effects_UNSTABLE: [localStorageEffect('@post_' + postId)],
});
```

Then I realized that I was pretty a rookie playing with fire and that I shall ask people who are knowledgeable about Recoil on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an array:

```
const postIds = atom({
  key: 'postIds',
  default: [],
  effects_UNSTABLE: [localStorageEffect('postIds')],
});
```

This way you manage the list of ids in one atom and those ids can refer to different `atomFamily`s that hold the content data of the posts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use atomFamily to manage your posts. You can use another atom to manage the post ids, if you want to add and delete posts.

```
const postsFamily = atomFamily({
  key: 'postsFamilyKey',
  default: [0, 0],
});

function PostListItem({postID}) {
  const post = useRecoilValue(postsFamily(postID));
  return (
    <div>
      Post ID: {postID}
      Post: {post}
    </div>
  );
}
```